# i preg_replace and get only last char of the statement. help

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've got a terrible problem. There are a lot of constructions like {{SOME_WORDS}} in my string and I want to change it for $lang['some_word']. For this reason I use something like:

```
$cache=preg_replace('/({{)+([A-Z_])+(}})/u','$2',$cache);
```

and got only last char of SOME_WORDS "S". The next problem is to put $lang[strtolower($2)] into preg_replace second argument. Or there could be another solution?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the `+` inside the parentheses. like this:

`$cache=preg_replace('/({{)+([A-Z_]+)(}})/u','$2',$cache);`

Comment: ок, fine but how to put $lang[strtolower($2)] into preg_replace second argument?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$cache = preg_replace("/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/e", "strtolower($1)", $cache);
```

Comment: that will change the string to lower case but i'm still got a error while putting $lang[strtolower($1)]